# Capybara Rails Rspec _ find css attributes/values

Tags: css, rspec, attributes, capybara

I'm searching to find values like line-height: for

```
<body class="custom_background">

    <div id="main_page" style="position:relative; margin:0 auto; ">


<div class="trex_title">
```

css:

```
element.style { }

.trex_title {
    width: 100%;
    color: #1d6b9c;
    line-height: 15px;
    height: 100px; }
```

I'm trying with

```
puts page.find('div.trex_title')['line-height']
```

[code screenshot/ snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24pOY.png)

Answer (score 1):

`element['xxx']` gets the property/attribute value of the element on the page.  Since CSS style values are not direct element properties or attributes that won't work. From your code you also appear to want the computed style of the element so you will need to do this using JS. If you're using the latest Capybara (3.2.x) you can do this with

```
find('div.trex_title').evaluate_script("window.getComputedStyle(this)['line-height']")
```

or if using older Capybara you can do

```
el = find('div.trex_title')
evaluate_script("window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0])['line-height']", el)
```